# CSS Relative and Absolute Positioned Elements Stretch the Container

Tags: css, height, css-position

Can you help me with my dilemma? I have a container (BODY in this case) that has `position:relative` set. Inside it I have two div's. One `relative` and one `absolute` positioned (in this order).

The problem is that whenever I set some `margin-top` to the `relative` positioned element, the container's height (`body` in this case) stretches vertically.

For example, even though I have set `height: 100%` to the container, its size when viewed is 100% + the `margin-top` of the `relative` positioned child element.

Here's a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/xJ75R/7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you should not give a relative position to the body, since body takes up the whole page.

Anyway, be specific when applying the relative position to another element, so if you have a class of "lists" then use

```
.lists { position: relative; top: something; left: something }
```

or margin, or whichever rule.

If you are just having problems with the body tag after giving some margin to ANOTHER element (though I do not see how this would happen), then give the body a margin of 0, like:

```
body { margin: 0; }
```

and if that doesn't work then use !important like

```
body { margin: 0 !important; }
```

On a side note, use firebug addon for firefox to make your CSS life easier and see what's happening on the fly.